# Set index statistics after insert in Firebird database

Tags: firebird

I would like to automate the process of setting index statistics in a Firebird database so that it doesn't require a database administrator to run the command, or a user to click a button.

Since the statistics only need to be recalculated after a large number of inserts or deletes, I am considering using an After Insert and After Delete trigger to keep track of how many inserts or deletes have taken place, and then run a procedure to set index statistics based on that value.

My question is whether there is anything to watch out for when setting the index statistics in this manner on a live database. To be clear, I am not rebuilding indexes, but recalculating index statistics only. It is quite possible that this would occur during a mass import or delete operation. Would calculating index statistics during a mass import or delete have the potential to cause any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to recalculate index statistics on a live database, while it is in use. It is also safe to do that in PSQL, e.g. in a stored procedure. For example I'm running a scheduled batch job in the night, which executes a stored procedure recalculating statistics for all indexes.

I'm not sure if it is wise to do that in a trigger, because triggers in Firebird fire per row and not per statement, thus you have to make sure to run that in some kind of conditional branch in your PSQL body.